# How to find out the geolocation in bing map SOAP service

Tags: .net, wpf, bing

I am calling Bing map SOAP service to get an image from the web and I would like to add some stuff that is not supported directly. I have the image and the center location geocode. However, in order to be able to draw something that actually makes sense, I would need to know the geo code on either corner.

Is there a way to get this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a series of blog posts on this a long time ago which you can find here:

http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/ve-imagery-service-and-custom-icons/
http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/ve-imagery-service-polygons-and-polylines/
http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2009/02/22/drawing-routes-with-the-ve-web-service/
http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2009/02/14/veimagery-service-pixel-to-latlong-calculations/